# Salesforce knowledgebase sitemap.xml

Tags: force.com, pagereference

Regarding [this article](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-sitemap-for-a-salesforce-knowledge-public-knowledge-base) I create dynamic sitemap for knowledgebase.

I can't set my page name to `sitemap.xml` because of dot, only `sitemap`.
And my sitemap available via link `http://domain/sitemap` instead of `http://domain/sitemap.xml`

How can I set up correct mapping to `sitemap.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, it's impossible to upload a file called sitemap.xml. I had the same issue years ago, tried to solve it with a custom URL rewriter class, this doesn't work either.

I ended up creating a 301-redirect from sitemap.xml to sitemap. Google will follow 301-redirect, therefore that shouldn't be an issue.