# How to expose sitemap to Google

Tags: force.com-sites

Is there any way to submit the Sitemap visualforce page as Sitemap.xml at Google Webmasters tool? I am unable to set the mapping of sitemap page as google takes only xml files for sitemap. 
As per this article [Salesforce knowledgebase sitemap.xml](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18313/salesforce-knowledgebase-sitemap-xml) 301 redirect is a solution from sitemap.xml to sitemap.

Can any one help me out with it -how to create a 301 redirect from sitemap.xml to sitemap or any other solution for this problem?